# Remove space with in string in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi i need to remove space within string .can any one help me with these.

```
String1 = "Biotin-dPEG <REFERENCE ID="9869" TYPE="trademark"/>n-azide products are single molecular weight dPEG <REFERENCE ID="9869" TYPE="trademark"/> products that permit biotin labeling with precise spacing" .
```

I need to remove space before `<REFRENCE ID = "9869 ...>` in string1.

Comment: Oracle is a database.  It is not normally used to do string manipulations on individual values.  PL/SQL is a scripting language associated with Oracle.  But, if you are using that, then the string is defined using `:=`, not `=`.  Hence, I don't understand the question.

Comment: try **trim** function

Comment: sure sorry for not cleary mentioning this earlier

Comment: "Biotin-dPEG <REFERENCE ID="9869" TYPE="trademark"/>n-azide products are single molecular weight dPEG <REFERENCE ID="9869" TYPE="trademark"/> products that permit biotin labeling with precise spacing"  i need to remove space before <REFRENCE> .

Comment: @mohsen.b - what do you think will be the result of trim()?

Comment: I need to remove only befre <Ref> tag not for all the string so i thought trim function will not work.

Comment: sorry i didn't see last line.

Comment: The question, as it stands right now, is unclear. From reading the answers and comments, it seems what you need is to remove the first space whenever you find this string: `' <REFERENCE '` (the first and the last character are spaces; the first space should be removed, the second should remain). This should be added **to the question itself** and not in comments and such. Or, if you want to remove space before `'<REFERENCE_ID_NUMBER` also, then say "I need to remove all  spaces before `<REFERENCE`. Or whatever the very precise statement of the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Using `regexp_replace`:

```
with t(col) as (
  select 'Biotin-dPEG <REFERENCE ID="9869" TYPE="trademark"' from dual
)
-- test data. Dont mind the above --

select
  regexp_replace(col, '\s+(<REFERENCE)','\1')
from t;
```

Produces:

```
Biotin-dPEG<REFERENCE ID="9869" TYPE="trademark"
```

Comment: Thanks @GurV . i modified this little and it worked .thanks for your valuable time and suggestion.

Comment: select regexp_replace(col, '\s+(<REFERENCE ID)','\1')
from table

Comment: @Animesh The `with` part was anyway to build a test table using CTE. Glad if it helped

Comment: What happens if the string is `Biotin-dPEG <REFERENCE TYPE="trademark" ID="9869" />`?

Comment: @MT0 Previously I thought if we're looking for `<REFERENCE ID`, but now OP says he want only `<REFERENCE`. So, updated.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all space surrounding `=`

```
select  regexp_replace('String1 = "Biotin-dPEG <REFERENCE ID="9869" TYPE="trademark"/>n-azide products are single molecular weight dPEG <REFERENCE ID = "9869" TYPE="trademark"/> products that permit biotin labeling with precise spacing" .
','\s*=\s*','=')
from    dual
```

---

```
String1="Biotin-dPEG <REFERENCE ID="9869" TYPE="trademark"/>n-azide products are single molecular weight dPEG <REFERENCE ID="9869" TYPE="trademark"/> products that permit biotin labeling with precise spacing" .
```

Here is a simple demo

```
select  regexp_replace('A =  1,B=   2,C=3,D=  4,E   =  5','\s*=\s*','=')
from    dual
```

---

```
A=1,B=2,C=3,D=4,E=5
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/olap.112/e17122/dml_functions_2068.htm

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/ap_posix.htm#SQLRF020

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE data ( string ) AS
SELECT 'Biotin-dPEG <REFERENCE ID="9869" TYPE="trademark"/>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Biotin-dPEG <REFERENCE TYPE="trademark" ID="9869"/>' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         UPDATEXML(
           xml,
           '/root/REFERENCE[@ID="9869"][1]/preceding-sibling::text()',
           RTRIM(
             EXTRACT(
               xml,
               '/root/REFERENCE[@ID="9869"][1]/preceding-sibling::text()'
             )
           )
         ).getClobVal(),
         '^<root>|</root>$|^<root/>$'
       ) AS string
FROM   ( SELECT XMLType( '<root>' || string || '</root>' ) AS xml
         FROM   DUAL );
```

**Output**:

```
STRING
--------------------------------------------------
Biotin-dPEG<REFERENCE ID="9869" TYPE="trademark"/>
Biotin-dPEG<REFERENCE TYPE="trademark" ID="9869"/>
```